# Tesla Near Mars Orbit

Tags: spacex, time, tesla-roadster

When will the Tesla Roadster come into a near Mars orbit as shown in the SpaceX simulation shown in Elon Musk's [tweet](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/961083704230674438/photo/1)? Is it 10 years, 20 years or when?

Comment: It's already in that orbit. It will take about 6 months to cross Mars' orbit for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

It's already in that orbit. It will take about 6 months to cross Mars' orbit for the first time.